# Возможно ли сохранить веса в следующем виде?

Tags: pytorch

Я поставил обучаться torchvision модель, весь процесс длился 8 часов, по завершении среда kaggle перезагрузилась и сохраненный .pth файл с весами удалился, веса остались в следующем виде в результате работы функции тренировки, есть ли возможность их сохранить и использовать в модели?

```
[(0.9518927540811314,
0.7595856701384914,
0.6607423761121454,
tensor(0.8284, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)),
…]
```